# React-Router with child in Go how does it work?

Tags: go, reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm trying to use react-router with a server in Go.

I did some tests but I can not do what I want.

My react components :

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>App</h2>
            <li><Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link></li>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

var Page1 = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>Page 1</h2>
            <li><Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link></li>
            </div>

        )
    }
})

var Page2 = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>Page 2</h2>
            <li><Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link></li>
            </div>

        )
    }
})
```

My react routing :

```
   ReactDOM.render((<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="page1" component={Page1} />
      <Route path="page2" component={Page2} />
    </Route>
  </Router>), document.getElementById('app'))
```

my go server :

```
func Render(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        RenderHTMLPage(w, "index.html")
}

func main() {
        goji.Get("/page1", Render)
        goji.Get("/page2", Render)
        goji.Get("/", Render)
        goji.Serve()
    }
```

My problem is when i click on Link in 'App' Component, for example :

```
<li><Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link></li>
```

url changes like that

> http://localhost:8000/page1

But actual component is already App and not Page1, so url changes but not component.
And if i load directly url, i have the same result.

Does anyone help me ?
Thank's :)

Comment: Your `Render` method is never going to write anything but the index, you have it hard coded.

Comment: no my index.html is juste a file a with a div with id="app"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a go question, but a react question, you need to render the App component's children in order for the other two components to display, a la this code snippet taken from the docs for React Router (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#props-2):

```
const routes = (
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="groups" component={Groups} />
    <Route path="users" component={Users} />
  </Route>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* this will be either <Users> or <Groups> */}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: yes I 've realized my mistake after posting this message. I have forgot this line "{this.props.children}". Thank's a lot for your help :)